# NEST : Create Alias and set filter

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am very new to ES. While exploring NEST client for .Net I came across a situation which am not able to figure out how to achieve using NEST.Net.

Configuration : 
.Net 4.6.1
NEST 7.2.0

What I am trying is to set an alias on an existing index. I was able to achieve it using following.

```
await _client.Indices.PutAliasAsync(indexName, aliasName);
```

This creates an alias on index though alias is empty.

Now I wanted to achieve below structure.

```
"MyIndexName" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "MyAliasName" : {
        "filter" : {
          "term" : {
            "MyFilterTerm" : "MyFilterTermValue"
          }
        }
      },
}
```

I used below snippet

```
await _client.Indices.PutAliasAsync(indexName, aliasName,
                                a => a.Filter<MyTestClass>(
                                    f => f.Term("MyFilterTerm", "MyFilterTermValue")));

public class MyTestClass {// not sure what this was supposed to be}
```

however this produces json as below.

```
"MyIndexName" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "MyAliasName" : {
        "filter" : {
          "term" : {
            "MyFilterTerm" : {
              "value" : "MyFilterTermValue"
            }
          }
        }
      },
}
```

How do I achieve the first JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two JSON formats for the `term` query in the `filter` clause are the equivalent. NEST typically emits the longer form of queries, which for a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) is

```
"term" : {
    "<field>" : {
        "value" : "<value>"
    }
}
```

as opposed to the short form

```
"term" : {
    "<field>" : "<value>"
}
```